# Rotate fragment to create a reflection on the x-axis

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

So basically I have defined a fragment for a card game I am creating, I wish to reuse this fragment for both player 1 and player 2 (since they both have the same layout) however I want them to be a mirror of each other. How can this be achieved, I have research rotating a fragment but no answers so far have described how to do so in code, they only describe handling when the screen rotates.

The activity for a 1v1 game

```
package com.PigRam.magichelper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class OneVsOneDuelActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.one_vs_one_view);
}
}
```

The layout for the fragments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:baselineAligned="true">

<fragment android:name="com.PigRam.magichelper.PlayerOneDuelFragment"
    android:id="@+id/player_one_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>

<fragment android:name="com.PigRam.magichelper.PlayerTwoDuelFragment"
    android:id="@+id/player_two_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Currently the fragments layout just have a single button in their layout that I want to appear to indicate a players turn is over.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button android:text="@string/end_turn"
    android:id="@+id/end_turn_botton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Player 1's code (Player 2 is exactly the same)

```
package com.PigRam.magichelper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class OneVsOneDuelActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.one_vs_one_view);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that if you're using Android v3.0+ you could reuse the same fragment and have the 2nd instance rotate it's view by 180 degrees using [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29) (after setting the pivot point to be 0.5, 0.5)

Comment: So I would need to get each instance of the fragment right by using getById or something similar, then casting to fragment then rotating?
Or can I just rotate the current View?

Comment: this isnt possible, I have tried calling container.setRotation in my Fragment class and it throws an exception

Answer (score 1):

add that fragment in the relative layout and set rotation to 180

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:rotation="180">

            <fragment
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```